# Intercept get return value

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, get, set, accessor

I would like to intercept the return value in a virtual property with something like that:

```
...
[InterceptionTag]
public virtual string Name {get; set;}
...
```

I have code that I have to put in a lot of properties and I don't want to replicate this code because I want to return a modified value for the properties.

Thanks!!

Comment: [PostSharp does this](http://www.postsharp.net/aspects/intercept-property-field). Maybe there is another alternative if you provide a bit more context.

Comment: DI container (i.e. [Unity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660891(v=PandP.20).aspx)) may provide such ability too...